# WAMP server shows red icon even though ports are not in used

Tags: php, wampserver

i have wamp server 3.0.0 installed 
port 80 and 3306 are empty.
i am getting error message in my Wampserver homepage reading :

> *** ERROR *** The PHP configuration loaded file is: - should be: C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.17/bin/php.ini or c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.15/phpforapache.ini

and my php error log file has errors:

> PHP Warning:  chmod(): Permission denied in C:\wamp\scripts\config.inc.php on line 68
>
> PHP Warning:  symlink(): Cannot create symlink, error code(1314) in C:\wamp\scripts\wampserver.lib.php on line 81
>
> PHP Warning:  symlink(): Cannot create symlink, error code(1314) in C:\wamp\scripts\wampserver.lib.php on line 90

No errors in mysql log file.

Comment: have you check the permissions on your server, to have read and write permissions?

Comment: yes i have checked and it has R/W permissions

Comment: one other question you write that you have some red icon? have you screenshot?

Comment: thanks for the help, but i uninstalled 3.0 and installed 2.5 and it is working all well. Maybe I guess 3.0 is a newly released version so it might have bunch of bugs to solve.

Comment: But the problem/Question is still alive and very much to be solved SOFians!

Comment: you can also try https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html